# Rails Activerecord creating links and comma separated values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the event that I have a model return an array, such as:

```
Person:
  has_many :websites
```

And Websites is another model, that has a value 'url', and 'name'

How might I go about presenting a comma-separated, linked list in a table for these items, where I link to the model itself, not the target URL?

I tried this kind of approach:

```
<%= person.websites.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

And that gets me a nice list of "Site1" or "Site2, Site3".

I tried to add `link_to` to the mix, and met with failure.

```
<%= person.websites.map {|website| link_to website.name, website_path }.join(', ') %>
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Output:

```
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"websites"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Pretty sure I'm missing something simple.

Update:

Per comment, I've updated it to `website_path(website)`, but the output is now stringified before it gets rendered:

```
<td>&lt;a href=&quot;/websites/1&quot;&gt;Site1&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href=&quot;/websites/2&quot;&gt;Site2&lt;/a&gt;</td>
```

The desired output would look something like this:

```
<p>
  <strong>Site(s):</strong>
  <a href="/websites/1">Site1</a>, <a href="/websites/2">Site2</a>
</p>
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What output do you get? And is that space before `.join` just a typo?  That would certainly break it.

Comment: Your website_path needs a website so website_path(website) , hope this is one step into the right direction.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom - updated with output, and removed extraneous space.

Comment: Can you write an example of the expect output. If you just need the url then you dont need link_to

Comment: I don't want the site's url, rather the the link to the website model itself, where a user can view the site's attributes (name, url, and more)

Comment: So is the output like this? "name1, www.site.com/name1, name2, www.site.com/name2"

Comment: To avoid the output to be _stringified_ add `.html_safe` at the end.. I hope you understand the security implications of this.

Comment: @fguillen This, in combination with @sonnyhe2002's answer worked. What's the security concern with `html_safe`?

Comment: @MikeFiedler http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 1):

The website path definitely need to pass in the website variable. And maybe it's a good idea to return it in an array, so you have an array of arrays before your join(', ')

```
<%= person.websites.map {|website| [website.name, website_url(website)] } %>
```

Comment: Adding the `website_path(website)` helped some, but placing the brackets around the link_to statement to return as an array value barfs with a: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Answer (score 1):

`<%= person.websites.map {|website| link_to(website.name, website_path(website) }.join(', ').html_safe %>`